# js file not loading when parameter passed number are increase in url - c#

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I've created a button in Index.aspx which is linked to master page.

In master page

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lay.js"></script>
```

In lay.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#a").click(function () {
       window.location = "hello.aspx/dhc/12/po";
   });
});
```

Hello.aspx page loads with the following errors:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html:     "http://localhost:64173/hello.aspx/c/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js". 12:9
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:64173/hello.aspx/c/js/bootstrap.min.js". 12:10
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:64173/hello.aspx/c/js/lay.js". 12:11
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery-1.11.1.min.js:3
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < bootstrap.min.js:3
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

What mistake have I done?

If I add

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="../../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/lay.js"></script>
```

Then it works, but if I increase the number of parameters from 3 to 4, then again I have to add extra dots (relative path) to reach there. How can we make it independent of the number of parameters passed.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Change your CSS and JS links to use absolute paths rather than relative:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
```

and

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lay.js"></script>
```

The leading `/` signifies the root of the virtual server, and therefore becomes independent of where the current script is executing.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/js/")%>jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/js/")%>bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/js/")%>lay.js"></script>
```

The above code worked.